# Linphone Android debug app - how to connect to SIP account

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am trying to build and run the following Linphone app: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/tree/release/5.1

However, when using the assistant to connect to a SIP account I getting the following stack-trace:

```
2023-06-05 11:24:54.487 12702-12702 libc                    org.linphone.debug                   A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 12702 (.linphone.debug), pid 12702 (.linphone.debug)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.596 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A  pid: 12702, tid: 12702, name: .linphone.debug  >>> org.linphone.debug <<<
2023-06-05 11:24:54.806 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #01 pc 000000000085143c  /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (_get_identity+96)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.806 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #02 pc 0000000000851818  /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (linphone_account_creator_create_proxy_config+60)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.806 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #03 pc 0000000000851ad4  /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (linphone_account_creator_create_account_in_core+8)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.806 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #04 pc 00000000008085c0  /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (Java_org_linphone_core_AccountCreatorImpl_createAccountInCore+24)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.806 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #12 pc 0000000000025e6a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes19.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/base.apk!classes19.dex (deleted) (org.linphone.core.AccountCreatorImpl.createAccountInCore+6)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.807 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #18 pc 000000000000c320  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes15.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/base.apk!classes15.dex (deleted) (org.linphone.activities.assistant.viewmodels.GenericLoginViewModel.createAccountAndAuthInfo+188)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.807 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #24 pc 0000000000042092  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes7.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/base.apk!classes7.dex (deleted) (org.linphone.databinding.AssistantGenericAccountLoginFragmentBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick+30)
2023-06-05 11:24:54.807 12904-12904 DEBUG                   pid-12904                            A      #30 pc 000000000000a098  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes9.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/org.linphone.debug-dyfVZCnnDJPISTU3kRD9rg==/base.apk!classes9.dex (deleted) (org.linphone.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick+8)
2023-06-05 11:24:55.751   471-550   InputDispatcher         system_process                       E  channel 'b6f63cb org.linphone.debug/org.linphone.activities.assistant.AssistantActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (12702) for package org.linphone.debug ----------------------------
2023-06-05 11:24:55.751   471-550   InputDispatcher         system_process                       E  channel '6b37690 org.linphone.debug/org.linphone.activities.main.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2023-06-05 11:24:55.789   471-3330  ActivityManager         system_process                       E  getPackageFerformanceMode--ComponentInfo{org.linphone.debug/org.linphone.activities.main.MainActivity}----org.linphone.debug
```

I have downloaded and installed the app from the [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.linphone&gl=GB) and it works as expected. Are there settings that need to be adjusted when the app is built this way? Or is there an issue in the debug code/my setup that I can't see?

Comment: UPDATE
I was able to get success by reverting back to release version 5.0. Can't track the issue down on the alpha channel (could be related to my hardware), so will wait until that build reaches release and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [linphone-android's source code](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-android/-/blob/release/5.1/app/src/main/java/org/linphone/activities/assistant/viewmodels/GenericLoginViewModel.kt#L125), do you correctly set the following fields of the account creator prior to calling accountCreator.createAccountInCore()?

```
accountCreator.username = username.value
accountCreator.password = password.value
accountCreator.domain = domain.value
accountCreator.displayName = displayName.value
accountCreator.transport = transport.value
```